# unable to resolv didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

If no input in search bar it returns me the folowing

```
The view wish.views.create_wish didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

```
def create_wish(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WishForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            wish = form.save(commit=False)
            wish.author = request.user
            wish.save()
            my_items = Wish.objects.filter(author=request.user)
            all_items = Wish.objects.filter(~Q(author=request.user))
            messages.success(request, (
               "Your location that you want to "
               "visit has been added to List !"))
            return render(request, "wish/wish.html", {'all_items': all_items, 'my_items': my_items})

    else:
        my_items = Wish.objects.filter(author=request.user)
        all_items = Wish.objects.filter(~Q(author=request.user))
        return render(request, "wish/wish.html", {'all_items': all_items, 'my_items': my_items})
```

I just want to go back to the page with a message " please enter a place"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here if your form is **not** valid there is None returning. That is the cause of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can try this:

```
def create_wish(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WishForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            wish = form.save(commit=False)
            wish.author = request.user
            wish.save()
            my_items = Wish.objects.filter(author=request.user)
            all_items = Wish.objects.filter(~Q(author=request.user))
            messages.success(request, (
               "Your location that you want to "
               "visit has been added to List !"))
            return redirect('/home/') #Add your path name here

    else:
        my_items = Wish.objects.filter(author=request.user)
        all_items = Wish.objects.filter(~Q(author=request.user))
    return render(request, "wish/wish.html", {'all_items': all_items, 'my_items': my_items})
```

I have modified this view.

Your above error will solve